# Wiki-like Module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, wiki

I'm basically looking for a wiki-like module for `drupal 7`.

I did a lot of research, but haven't come up with any evidence suggesting modules in drupal for wiki-like functionality.

I saw a tool `WikiTools` - but its only for Drupal 6 (full release) they do have an alpha-release as well for Drupal 7, but it hasn't been updated since March of 2011 thus probably not making it a good fit.

Does anyone have any modules for Drupal 7 that provide wiki functionality?

This would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a single contrib module will give you the wiki-like functionality in Drupal. You might have to get few modules to work together to get your wiki-like drupal site done.

I know that last update for [wikiTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/wikitools) was in 2013, but there is a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHsjjHzYOSg) that shows how to use wikiTools to build a wiki in drupal 7.

Also, check [this post](http://www.civicactions.com/blog/modules_for_building_drupal_wikis) on how to get some contrib modules working together to build your wiki.